# OfficeWebApp turn off

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

I'm trying to disabe OfficeWEbApp in SP10 farm. 
Already did:
1) Disable with powershell.
2) Edit Xml.
Source (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/opal/2011/02/10/uninstall-or-disable-office-web-apps/)

Still, some users are complaining that documents are opening in officeapp.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Link :http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/08/disable-office-web-apps-enable-open-in-client-sharepoint.html

You need to remove WOPI bindings for the filetypes the users are still getting errors for firstly .
Secondly Change the Open in Client behavior for the sites the users are complaining by deactivating the feature needed .
If you run into issues deactivating it you refer the technet below:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2010/ee837418(v=office.14)#bkmk_deactiv_single